# Coco/R keeps telling me "'COMPILER' expected", even though I have the declaration

Tags: compiler-construction, cocor

As the title says, I'm having trouble using Coco/R. When I compile my file, Andromeda.atg, it gives me two errors:
"-- line 1 col 1: "COMPILER" expected"
"-- line 1352 col 5: name does not match grammar name"

I have no idea why this is happening. I tried moving my COMPILER Andromeda line to the top, but the same errors pop up.
Here's my entire file: http://pastebin.com/PezqZb6y

Thanks,
Theo

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why it was telling me that it couldn't find the COMPILER part. Visual Studio was adding some UTF8 characters in the start of the file, screwing Coco up.